# Vendor for real-time market single stock quote with C# API

Tags: real-time, quotes, stock

Is there such a thing?  I was trying to compare XIgnite, with free options like Google and Yahoo.   Does anyone have a recommendation?

I just need a service that can retrieve real-time up to the milisecond quote sporadically for one symbol at a time, preferably with a WebAPI.

Won't be able to afford Bloomberg and such.  This is only for light business use.  A couple hundreds a month is probably all.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify exactly how much you will be willing to pay. There are fairly expensive services like Bloomberg and Reuters. You used to be able to use OpenTick for free tick data, but they are not in business anymore.

How about trying QuantHouse? It will cost you some money, but they do have various APIs that you could leverage.

http://www.quanthouse.com/low-latency-market-data

Comment: Thanks I editted.   Definitely not Bloomberg and Reuters.  Was hoping for people that have used different things and some recommendations.